# Получить просроченную куку через Request.Cookies

Tags: c#, cookie, jwt

В браузере в куках есть просроченный access_token и действительный refresh_token. Чтобы обновить токен, мне нужно получить оба, но почему-то в `HttpContext.Request.Cookies` нет access_token'а. Как получить просроченный токен из куков?

Comment: Просроченных кук не существует. Если у неё кончилось время жизни, значит её больше нет. Выставляйте время жизни куки больше чем срок её действия.

Comment: @AlexeyTen да, и правда в этом проблема была. Но не понимаю, почему куки не пропадают из браузера самого? Ну, через F12 их видно, хотя все обновляю. А в HttpContext.Request.Cookies нет.